# Using karate not able to launch edgedriver

Tags: karate

Background:
Configure driver = { type: 'msedgedriver' ,executable: 'path of your driver' webDriverSession: { capabilities: { browserName: 'edge' }}}

Scenario:

- driver 'http://'

Console output
Microsoft edge webdriver was started successfully
Error com.intuit.karate
Java.util.list org.apache.http.client.utils.URIbuilder.getPatgsegments()

Comment: there may be a lack of info on edgedriver, do see if you can contribute code or knowledge on this to the community